# strange behaveor of ffmpeg while writing using ffvhuff codec

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, codec

In my application I need to save `yuv422p` frames into `AVI` using `ffmpeg`. I wrote a function that does this, but to my surprise the file format is `bgr0` that is incorrect.

This is my code:

```cpp
bool write_avi()
{
    try
    {
        ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&m_format_context, nullptr, nullptr, m_filePath.c_str());
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("context allocation error");
        }

        m_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_FFVHUFF);

        if (m_codec == nullptr)
        {            
            throw std::runtime_error("cannot find appropriate codec");
        }

        m_stream = avformat_new_stream(m_format_context, m_codec);
        if (m_stream == nullptr)
        {            
            throw std::runtime_error("stream creating error");
        }

        m_codec_context = avcodec_alloc_context3(m_codec);
        if (m_codec_context == nullptr)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("context creating error");
        }

        m_stream->codecpar->codec_id   = m_codec->id;
        m_stream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
        m_stream->codecpar->format     = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P;
        m_stream->codecpar->width      = width;
        m_stream->codecpar->height     = height;
        m_stream->time_base            = av_d2q(1.0 / m_fps, 120);
        m_codec_context->codec_id      = m_codec->id;
        m_codec_context->width         = width;
        m_codec_context->height        = height;
        m_codec_context->time_base     = AVRational{1, m_fps};
        m_codec_context->framerate     = AVRational{m_fps, 1};
        m_codec_context->pix_fmt       = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P;
        m_codec_context->gop_size      = 10;
        m_codec_context->max_b_frames  = 1;    

        AVDictionary* codec_options(0);        
        av_dict_set(&codec_options, "context_model", "1", 0);
        
        ret = avcodec_open2(m_codec_context, m_codec, &codec_options);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("context initializtion error");
        }

        ret = avio_open(&m_format_context->pb, m_filePath.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("av context initialization error");
        }

        if (avformat_write_header(m_format_context, nullptr) < 0)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("header writing error");
        }        

        m_frame         = av_frame_alloc();
        m_frame->width  = m_width;
        m_frame->height = m_height;
        m_frame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P;

        ret = av_frame_get_buffer(m_frame, 0);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("frame buffer allocation error");
        }

        m_packet = av_packet_alloc();
        if (!m_packet)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("packat initializtion error");
        }

        // write frames
        for(size_t i = 0;i < 100;i ++)
        {
            av_init_packet(m_packet);
            m_packet->data = nullptr;
            m_packet->size = 0;

            ret = av_frame_make_writable(m_frame);
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("frame make writable error: " + avError(ret));
            }

            ret = av_image_fill_arrays(m_frame->data, m_frame->linesize, data[i], m_codec_context->pix_fmt, m_frame->width, m_frame->height, m_align);
            if (ret < 0)
            {                
                throw std::runtime_error("frame fill error");
            }

            m_frameNumber++;
            m_frame->pts     = m_frameNumber;
            m_frame->pkt_dts = m_frameNumber;

            ret = avcodec_send_frame(m_codec_context, m_frame);
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("encoder error");
            }

            ret = avcodec_receive_packet(m_codec_context, m_packet);
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("packet receive error");
            }

            m_packet->stream_index = m_stream->index;

            m_packet->pts = m_frameNumber;
            m_packet->dts = m_frameNumber;
            av_packet_rescale_ts(m_packet, m_codec_context->time_base, m_stream->time_base);

            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(m_format_context, m_packet);
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("frame writing error");
            }

            av_packet_unref(m_packet);
        }

    }
    catch(const std::exception &ex)
    {

    }
}
```

The file is recorded without problems but if I check it with ffprobe the pix format is bgr0:

```
>> ffprobe ./test0.avi
>> Input #0, avi, from 'test0.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:21.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 154218 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: ffvhuff (FFVH / 0x48564646), bgr0, 1280x720, 154451 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
```

of course, when playing the video, there is some garbage picture.
I don't understand what the problem may be here, I will be glad of any help.

My system is Ubuntu 20.04

ffplay version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1

P.S. I've tested the same code using `ffv1` codec and the output pixel format suddenly has changed to `yuv444p`. but while using `h.264` the output format is written correctly (`yuv422p`). Looks like ffmpeg can change the output pixel format depending on some of its ideas.

P.S.S the `ffmpeg`/`ffvhuff` supports for `yuv422p`:

```
>> ffmpeg -h encoder=ffvhuff
>> ...
>> Supported pixel formats: yuv420p yuv422p yuv444p yuv411p yuv410p yuv440p gbrp gbrp9le gbrp10le gbrp12le gbrp14le gbrp16le gray gray16le yuva420p yuva422p yuva444p gbrap yuv420p9le yuv420p10le yuv420p12le yuv420p14le yuv420p16le yuv422p9le yuv422p10le yuv422p12le yuv422p14le yuv422p16le yuv444p9le yuv444p10le yuv444p12le yuv444p14le yuv444p16le yuva420p9le yuva420p10le yuva420p16le yuva422p9le yuva422p10le yuva422p16le yuva444p9le yuva444p10le yuva444p16le rgb24 bgra
```

Comment: Each encoder supports a limited set of pixel formats. Running `ffmpeg -h encoder=$NAME` will print a line with that list near the top. If the specified pixel format is not present, ffmpeg will negotiate the closest match.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Gyan. Sure, I've checked that before and `yuv422p` is supported, see my updated question.